# Filtrar dataframe a partir de una tupla

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe(df2)

```
      Nombrearchivo                         Numero        PosicionRegistro
20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg     208-13567             588
20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg     208-1356              588
20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg     208-567958-           588
TOMAS_131225713254987197.pdf               017-30402-            649
```

y la tupla contiene(resultadoNombreArchivo)

```
[('20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg', 85, 17),
('20161020_113352_131221557853238556.jpg', 82, 21), 
('20161020_113422_131221557754328771.jpg', 79, 20), 
('20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg', 76, 18),
('20161020_113437_131221557662296937.jpg', 76, 19), 
('20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg', 76, 22)]
```

Necesito mostrar los datos del dataframe en donde el nombre del archivo coincide con el dato de la tupla, probe varios metodos que estuve revisando con lamba pero en todos no pude avanzar nada un ejemplo de lo que llegue a probar es

```
resultNombreArchivo = process.extract(inputNombreArchivo,InputDataSet["nombreArchivo"],limit=6,scorer=fuzz.ratio)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(InputDataSet)

print(df2[df2["nombreArchivo"].apply(lambda x: resultNombreArchivo[0][0] in x)])
```

Comment: Si `tupla` es la lista de tuplas que estás mostrando entonces deberías usar: `tupla[0][0]`. ¿O estás iterando cada elemento? Tal vez puedas actualizar tu pregunta con un poco más de código.

Comment: con tu modificacion obtengo TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: A lo mejor actualizas tu pregunta con el bloque de código completo, si me pongo a adivinar es más difícil ayudarte ;-)

Comment: gracias Cesar, ya lo actualice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería funcionar como te mencioné en mi comentario:

```
>>> data = [
...   {'NombreArchivo': '20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg', 'Numero': '208-13567', 'PosicionRegistro': 588},
...   {'NombreArchivo': '20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg', 'Numero': '208-1356', 'PosicionRegistro': 588},
...   {'NombreArchivo': '20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg', 'Numero': '208-567958-', 'PosicionRegistro': 588},
...   {'NombreArchivo': 'TOMAS_131225713254987197.pdf', 'Numero': '017-30402-', 'PosicionRegistro': 649},
... ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> resultNombreArchivo = [                                                   
...   ('20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg', 85, 17),
...   ('20161020_113352_131221557853238556.jpg', 82, 21), 
...   ('20161020_113422_131221557754328771.jpg', 79, 20), 
...   ('20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg', 76, 18),
...   ('20161020_113437_131221557662296937.jpg', 76, 19), 
...   ('20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg', 76, 22) 
... ]
```

Usando `apply`:

```
>>> df['NombreArchivo']
0    20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg
1    20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg
2    20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg
3              TOMAS_131225713254987197.pdf
Name: Nombrearchivo, dtype: object
>>> df['NombreArchivo'].apply(lambda x: resultNombreArchivo[0][0] in x)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
>>> print(df[df['NombreArchivo'].apply(lambda x: resultNombreArchivo[0][0] in x)])
                            NombreArchivo     Numero  PosicionRegistro
0  20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg  208-13567               588
```

**Actualización**

Si quieres filtrar tu `DataFrame` para saber cuáles de ellos contienen archivos que estén dentro de las tuplas, puedes usar [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas.DataFrame.isin):

```
>>> nombres_archivos = [tupla[0] for tupla in resultNombreArchivo]
>>> nombres_archivos
['20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg', '20161020_113352_131221557853238556.jpg', '20161020_113422_131221557754328771.jpg', '20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg', '20161020_113437_131221557662296937.jpg', '20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg']
>>> df['NombreArchivo'].isin(nombres_archivos)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: NombreArchivo, dtype: bool
>>> print(df[df['NombreArchivo'].isin(nombres_archivos)])
                            NombreArchivo       Numero  PosicionRegistro
0  20161020_113502_131221557378544949.jpg    208-13567               588
1  20161020_113448_131221555449704589.jpg     208-1356               588
2  20161020_113348_131221557962771773.jpg  208-567958-               588
```

Comment: Gracias cesar en un momento lo voy a probar, una consulta como seria para q traiga todos los valores el df q se encuentran en la tupla ya q solo esta el q finaliza en 49 y no esta incluido el q finaliza en 89